# Django: Using .distinct() on a query causes invalid DB query

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-models

I am trying to get the list of distinct store_names in the list of submissions.

My very simple Django model:

```
class Submission(models.Model):  
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)  
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null= True, blank=True)  
    store_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

If I do:
`stores = Submission.objects.values_list('store_name', flat=True)`
Then the printed result is fine:
`[u'amazon.com', u'amazon.com', u'amazon.com', u'buy.com']`

However - if I add **.distinct()** to the query, then I get **This query is not supported by the database.**

Any ideas on why this would be happening? I've played around with using *values* instead of *valueslist* with no luck.

(Latest django release, Python 2.6, OS X, Google App Engine)

Comment: To lighten the problem up a bit you could run `print stores.query` and post the raw sql output here!

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT app_submission.store_name FROM app_submission

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Appengine Datastore API doen't support `distinct` functionality. That's what the error you get says, so you can't do it.

All you can do is to filter not unique questions after you fetch the results like this:

```
stores = Submission.objects.values_list('store_name', flat=True)
unique_stores = []
for store in stores:
    if store not in unique_stores:
        unique_stores.append(store)
```

Comment: it looks like GAE does support DISTINCT now https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference#Syntax